# Solving a task in cosmology using Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I am looking for a piece of code that takes a list of redshifts (i.e. numbers) as input from the user, separated by spaces and in one go, and then automatically assigns them to variables like a,b,c,d.....m,n,o.

For example, if the user gives "0.32 0.53 0.77 0.91 1.1 1.4" as an input, the program should assign 0.32 to variable a, 0.53 to variable b, 0.77 to variable c, and so on. I do not expect the user to input more than 10 numbers.

I have been trying to the best of my knowledge to use the raw_input function for this, but to no success thus far.

Following this I am planning to use the simple formula `A=3800/(1+a)` to find the shortest rest-frame wavelength that a body at redshift "a" would be seen to emit in the optical range, and repeat this process for all the other bodies whose redshifts have been given by the user. This part should present no problem however. My real stumbling block is as described above.

Comment: keep a dictionary of 'variables', e.g. d=dict();d['a']=0.32;d['b']=0.53;... then d['A']=3800/(1+d['a'])

Comment: Hi denfromufa, thanks for your comment. I tried something like di=dict();

di['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] = raw_input('Enter four numbers\n');
a = float(a);
b = float(b);
c = float(c);
d = float(d); but get the error that "name 'a' is not defined"

Comment: you got it completely wrong, i recommend going through basic python tutorial, e.g. from google. it looks like you do not even have basic understanding of programming workflow in python.

Comment: a,b,c,d=raw_input('bla\n').split(' ')

Comment: On what kind of system are you using version 2.0? That was released in 2000 and has not been supported with security fixes for a long time. Can't you upgrade to at least to the 2.7 series?

Comment: Hi Anthon, I'm actually using Python 2.7.5. I should have been more specific. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you got a string from a user using `raw_input()`:

```
astr = raw_input('Input: ')
```

Then, there are many ways you can handle this. But the easiest might be to just split that string into a list:

```
alist = astr.split(' ') # returns ['0.32', '0.53', '0.77', '0.91', '1.1', '1.4']
```

Since you probably want them to be floats instead of string, you can use a list comprehension:

```
alist = [float(val) for val in astr.split(' ')] # returns [0.32, 0.53, 0.77, 0.91, 1.1, 1.4]
```

You can also put it all in a dictionary:

```
dic = {j:float(val) for j, val in enumerate(astr.split(' '))}
```

If you want to name them by letters and if you are sure there will be less than 26, you can do this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
dic = {letters[j]:float(val) for j, val in enumerate(astr.split(' '))}
```

Finally, you could use `exec` but that's very bad form and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Hi Julien. Thanks for your clear and comprehensive response. I am expecting at most 15 lines of input from the user, hence the 26 letters would more than suffice for my purposes. I simply added the suggested lines of code to the top of the program. For a start, I followed these by a simple arithmetical expression such as A=9800/(1+a), which does not seem to execute - I'm getting the dreaded NameError: name 'a' is not defined. Could the version of my Python be the culprit? I'm using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Hi Solomon, I've just made an edit. As mentioned, you are creating dictionaries with the last two commands. For example, `dic = {letters[j]:float(val) for j, val in enumerate(astr.split(' '))}`. This means that no variable a, b, c, or d are created but instead they are all part of the dictionary `dic`. so your formula should be A = 9800/(1+dic['a']) ... Also, since I guess you want to do that for all values in the dictionaries, you can do it straight from the dictionary definition: `dic = {letters[j]:9800/(1+float(val)) for j, val in enumerate(astr.split(' '))}`

Comment: Hi Julien. The program is working perfectly now. I couldn't thank you enough for this. All the best. S